# How to create xPath of a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I have a html page like this.

```
<html>
<body>
<p>test html</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the xPath of this html page using javascript or jQuery. xPath might be like this

```
/html/body/p/...
```

Comment: HTML has a tree structure while xPath is linear. xPath shows you the path from your selected element up into the root, not the other way around.

Comment: The path to what exactly? Your whole document is a HTML page, what exactly should be the result of evaluating the XPath expression? @Gil, no, that's not true. XPath expressions can navigate trees in arbitrary ways, further towards the leaves or up to the root.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I stand corrected :)